# PHPUnit complains about Selenium

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, yii, phpunit

Sorry if this is trivial but I did not find any advice how to fix this.
I am on Ubuntu and need PHPUnit for my Yii project.
I have installed PHPUnit twice, by downloading and moving phpunit.phar to '/usr/local/bin' and by running:

```
composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=3.7.*"
```

Now I am trying to execute my Yii PHPUnit test:

```
phpunit unit/DbTest.php
```

And what I get is:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/yii-project/framework/test/CWebTestCase.php on line 12

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 
'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/yii-project/framework/test/CWebTestCase.php on line 12
```

So it seems that it can't find PHPUnit extension SeleniumTestCase.php. Then PHPUnit installation manual states that Selenium 'is included in the PHAR distribution of PHPUnit.'.
Can you suggest what do I do to make my Yii test work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I did to fix this:

1) I have downloaded selenium extensions from:
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/tree/master/PHPUnit/Extensions
and placed the entire PHPUnit directory under

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/yii-project/framework/test
```

At that point PHPUnit stopped complaining about missing SeleniumTestCase.php.

2) Then I got an error about missing file in

```
PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php
```

To fix this I commented out these lines in CTestCase.php:

```
//require_once('PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php');
//require_once('PHPUnit/Util/Filesystem.php'); // workaround for PHPUnit <= 3.6.11
//require_once('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');
```

Now I am able to run my tests.

Comment: If someone needs a older version of SeleniumTestCase.php, you may get it from here https://github.com/EHER/phpunit-all-in-one/blob/master/src/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php

Comment: what is mentioned by Alan has newer version of SeleniumTest2Case.php with name spaces.

Answer (score 9):

You need to install optional additional packages of `phpunit` for Yii testing to run

The packages you would need are

```
PHP_Invoker
DbUnit
PHPUnit_Selenium
phpunit-story
```

You can install them using composer by adding the following to `require-dev`

```
"phpunit/php-invoker": "*",
"phpunit/dbunit": ">=1.2",
"phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2",
"phpunit/phpunit-story": "*"
```

use the following commands to install the respective dependencies

```
composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit-selenium=*'
composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit-story=*'
composer global require 'phpunit/dbunit=*'
composer global require 'phpunit/php-invoker=*'
```

Comment: Thanks Manquer. Can you advise where do I install them(where do I place `composer.json` and run `composer install`)? Is it a project directory or framework dir?

Comment: It should be the project directory; Ideally you would configure a bin directory which should contain all the executables for your project; However since you are using global require; you can see my revised answer to solve your issue

Comment: Thanks. I had followed your advice and installed all these dependencies but I still had this error. Eventually I fixed this by following steps described in my reply.

Comment: glad you had it fixed :) .. if the error persisted it is likely because your phpunit and install locations were different, this happens when you have multiple versions installed etc, this can be overridden of course by installing in the test directory as you have done; and yii autoload class with load it. however changing the framework is not good idea; things may break and upgrading is difficult;

Comment: @RNKushwaha this is because there is a smal typo in the require-dev block : "phpunit/phpunit-story:*" should be "phpunit/phpunit-story": "*". Then it works like a charm :)

Comment: You are globally installing packages here...so these classes and libraries will be in your  `PHP include` path. What if you don't want to globally install? what o you do in this case?

Comment: Use the first method and put them in composer.json file in your project or use `composer require` to get same results.

Comment: @Manquer but it is still looking in the `PHP_include` not the `vendor` folder in the `/test` directory

Comment: You would have to look into your composer auto loader and configuration. Seems like you have non default composer config. This is a answer for the simple case of including dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me

```
sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Invoker
sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/DbUnit
sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Selenium
sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/phpunit-story
```

Comment: You are installing with pear...and pear is in your `PHP include` path. What about using composer? How does one add the `/vendor` path so the unit tests have access to the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

In time of replying this, it is necessary to little bit amend Manquer's response. It is necessary to edit CWebTestCase and include Selenium2TestCase.php instead of SeleniumTestCase.php and extending PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase instead of PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase. Php-invoker is not possible to install on Windows and it is not necessary.